# converting none (size-1 arrays) to scalars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am working on functions and i practice it by some codes (there is a bias because i am working on neural networks) and when i was doing square root function and i got an error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Here is the code which caused it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math


def somefunc(m,bias):
    y = round(math.sqrt(m))+ bias
    return y


y = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
z = somefunc(y,0)
plt.plot(y, z)
plt.xlabel("y")
plt.ylabel("func(y)")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use numpy methods to deal with multi-arrays :

**np.sqrt** instead of **math.sqrt**

**np.round** instead of **round**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math


def somefunc(m,bias):
    y = np.round(np.sqrt(m))+ bias
    return y


y = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
z = somefunc(y,0)
plt.plot(y, z)
plt.xlabel("y")
plt.ylabel("func(y)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well it works but should i use round, without round it seems a lot more relevant to this here http://www.analyzemath.com/function/graph-of-square-root-function.gif but thanks it works :D